# How to record speech in iphone?

Tags: iphone, voice-recording

I am new to iphone development.I want to create a application that records the voice and i can play the audio file when required. Please guide me .Please give some sample tutorials so it would be easy for me to understand.Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Apple has a [SpeakHere](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html) demo that is exactly what you describe.

Comment: protip: set a breakpoint in main and step into everything while it's working to understand how it works